# Magic popcount numbers

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, hexadecimal

There’s a [famous tricky algorithm for counting the number of set bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#Efficient_implementation) in a 32-bit unsigned integer:

```
int popcount(unsigned x) {
   x = (x & 0x55555555) + ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
   x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
   x = (x & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((x >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F);
   x = (x & 0x00FF00FF) + ((x >> 8) & 0x00FF00FF);
   x = (x & 0x0000FFFF) + ((x >>16) & 0x0000FFFF);
   return x;
}
```

I won’t explain it here. But imagine similar code for 512-bit integers! The hexadecimal constants would be huge, and form a pretty pattern. Your task is simply to **print this exact output**:

```
0x55555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555
0x33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f
0x00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff
0x0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff
0x00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff
0x0000000000000000ffffffffffffffff0000000000000000ffffffffffffffff0000000000000000ffffffffffffffff0000000000000000ffffffffffffffff
0x00000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

No trailing spaces, please — though a single trailing newline is optional.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Are we allowed to take input (as in something like 0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x)?

Comment: @ouflak No. ———

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>26</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

05AB1E uses the [CP-1252](http://www.cp1252.com) encoding.

```
9F„0x0NÍo×9ooNoo>÷hJ,
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=OUbigJ4weDBOw41vw5c5b29Ob28-w7doSiw&input=)

**Explanation**

```
9F                      # for N in [0 ... 8]
  „0x                   # push the string "0x"
     0NÍo×              # push 2**(N-2) zeroes
          9oo           # 2**2**9
                 ÷      # //
             Noo>       # (2**2**N+1)
                  h     # converted to base-16
                   J    # join everything to string
                    ,   # print with a newline
```

**Other versions that might be improved**

```
9F9ooNoo>÷h¾6o×J7o£R…0xÿ,
9F9ooNoo>÷h0žy×ìR7o£R…0xÿ,
9FX0No×1No×JCh7o×1K7o£…0xÿ,
8ÝovX0y×1y×JCh7o×1K7o£…0xÿ,
9F1NoÅ0D>)˜JCh1K7o×7o£…0xÿ,
```

Answer (score 20):

## Python 2, <strike>52</strike> <strike>49</strike> 46 bytes

The kth number is given by `2**512/(2**2**k + 1)`. This is for a 512 bit number, so it's trivial to extend the pattern to different widths.

```python
l=2;exec"print'0x%0128x'%(2**512/-~l);l*=l;"*9
```

3 bytes saved thanks to Dennis.
3 bytes saved thanks to xnor.

Comment: The advantages of arbitrary-precision integers...

Comment: Nice. [This](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59ta8iVWpGarFRQlJlXom5QoWpgaGRRoa6qYaSlZWpopK9bB2Rka1pna9kaWStpWf7/DwA "Python 2 – TIO Nexus") saves a few bytes.

Comment: Shorter to keep squaring: `l=2;exec"print'0x%0128x'%(2**512/-~l);l*=l;"*9`

Comment: It warms my heart to see Python in the vote-lead :)

Comment: Shouldn't the formula be `2**512/(2**2**k + 1)`?

Comment: @Mego Oops, fixed. The program did use the correct formula though.

Comment: @orlp Yep, I noticed that, which had me very confused for much longer than I should've been.

Comment: Curious: how did you figure out the formula and why does it work? Explanation would be cool :)

Comment: @TuukkaX I just have a lot of experience with bit twiddling hacks. I used Wolfram Alpha a lot to simplify sums and such. But basically I made the pattern `01010101`, `00010001`, `00000001`, and then multiplied those by `1`, `11`, `1111` to get the correct binary patterns. For example `01010101` you can get the formula for a certain width w by doing `sum 2^(2*k) for k = 0, w/2 - 1` and finding out it's `(2**w - 1)/3`.

Comment: Use `%#0130x`: `l=2;exec"print'%#0130x'%(2**512/-~l);l*=l;"*9`

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, <s>111</s> <s>110</s> 108 bytes

One byte saved thanks to @user59178.

```
<?=($p=str_pad)("0x",130,5).$p($s="\n0x",131,3);for($x=1;$x<65;$x*=2)echo($p($s,131,$p(0,$x,0).$p(f,$x,f)));
```

What´s the pattern for 1024 bits? :D

Comment: You can save a byte by using `$x<65` rather than `$i++<7`. This time I tested it and everything.

Answer (score 7):

## Vim, 32 bytes

`i5<CR>3<Esc>qqYpVrf$<C-V>{yPG1vr0q6@q<C-V>{I0x<Esc>`

I only need to manually write the first `5` and `3`, and the macro takes care of the rest, "doubling the bit count" each time it runs. The order of the steps in the macro is a bit weird (make a new `f` line, block-wise copy, reuse the visual block size to put `0`s in the `f` line), but it's the fastest variant I've found.

Answer (score 6):

## J, <s>46</s> 34 bytes

<s>I'm working on golfing this, but this baby likes to stay at 46 bytes...</s> Not anymore! -12 bytes thanks to miles!

```
'0x',"1'5','3','0f'(128$#)"{~2^i.7
```

[Try it online! :D](https://tio.run/nexus/j#S7S1MlCwUjD4r25Qoa6jZKhuqq6jbgzEBmnqGoZGFirKmkrVdUZxmXrm/zW5UpMz8hWU9BJ19XzcdJyD/gMA)

### Result

```
   '0x',"1'5','3','0f'(128$#)"{~2^i.7
0x55555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555
0x33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f
0x00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff00ff
0x0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff0000ffff
0x00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff00000000ffffffff
0x0000000000000000ffffffffffffffff0000000000000000ffffffffffffffff0000000000000000ffffffffffffffff0000000000000000ffffffffffffffff
0x00000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

---

For this answer, I needed (ideally) a verb with rank `0 1` so as to use it in the `u"v` definition of rank; however, miles observed that `0 _` was sufficient for the task at hand.

```
┌──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬──┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│= │< │<.│<:│> │>.│>:│+ │+.│+:│* │*.│*:│_ 0 0│_ 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│- │-.│-:│% │%.│%:│^ │^.│$ │$.│$:│~.│~:│0 0 0│0 _ _│0 _ _│0 0 0│2 _ 2│0 0 0│0 0 0│0 0 0│_ 1 _│_ _ _│_ _ _│_ 0 0│_ 0 0│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│| │|.│, │,.│,:│; │;:│# │#.│#:│! │/:│\:│0 0 0│_ 1 _│_ _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│1 _ _│_ 1 _│1 1 1│_ 1 0│0 0 0│_ _ _│_ _ _│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│[ │[:│] │{ │{.│{:│}.│}:│".│":│? │?.│a │_ _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│1 0 _│_ 1 _│_ 0 0│_ 1 _│_ 0 0│1 _ _│_ 1 _│0 0 0│_ 0 0│_ _ _│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│A │A.│b │C │C.│d │D │e │e.│E │E.│f │H │_ _ _│1 0 _│_ _ _│_ _ _│1 1 _│_ _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│0 _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│i │i.│i:│I │I.│j │j.│L │L.│M │o │o.│p │_ _ _│1 _ _│0 _ _│_ _ _│1 _ _│_ _ _│0 0 0│_ _ _│_ 0 0│_ _ _│_ _ _│0 0 0│_ _ _│
├──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼──┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
│p.│p:│q │q:│r │r.│s │s:│S │t │T │u:│x:│1 1 0│0 _ _│_ _ _│0 0 0│_ _ _│0 0 0│_ _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│_ _ _│
└──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴──┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Here you see a bunch of verbs' string representations with their respective ranks. [This is the script I used to generate it.](https://tio.run/nexus/j#TY5LT4NAFIX38yuOUF46jhh304IYNdFEV7rDijymdkwDFbBp08pfxxlMq8ld3Mf5zj19KRcIOCTz4ZMmnYlErNJhdQGuVmjrDYPBsEGetvmcQROiLBjxyErUWaO1Y06dYBImJ8en1uuo2zFOx@bR2Us83X4bb5F9mV5l18WNuJ3dyfuPh8dq@Vk3T@3z19qhzPBx7oBxh2RpI3PtF3P8ZaG2g4z5DlGDLJLDU/e3Mzu4ExXKQ8cx9TCY2CzEcCaLqnwXTTsAynarNBrxEcCMYuw6zUgWhap4ZPHIJMulVo867Fl66KwOJhH5vIJLma2E@28e/qXr@x8)

Comment: A verb with rank `0 _` is fine here. You can shorten it to 34 bytes with `'0x',"1'5','3','0f'(128$#)"{~2^i.7`

Comment: @miles Huh. I thought I tried that... cool! and I forgot about J's auto-row-fill feature, thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

### [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 43 bytes

```
:`
0x128$*5
:`5
3
;{:`33
0f
0(f+)(0+)
0$2$1
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=OmAKMHgxMjgkKjUKOmA1CjMKO3s6YDMzCjBmCjAoZispKDArKQowJDIkMQ&input=)

#### Explanation

This makes a lot of use of the generally underused `:` option which lets you print intermediate results, because it's a lot shorter to modify a single line than to build up the whole output.

```
:`
0x128$*5
```

This replaces the empty input with `0x` followed by 128 `5`s and prints it to generate the first line.

```
:`5
3
```

This one replaces the `5`s with `3`s to generate the second line and prints it as well.

```
;{:`33
0f
```

This is the last special-cased line and it turns every two `3`s into `0f` to generate the third line. This also starts a loop through the last two stages (`{`). However, this stage won't do anything after the first iteration except print the current state. The `;` suppresses the output at the very end of the program to avoid duplicating the last line.

```
0(f+)(0+)
0$2$1
```

This substitution now transforms each line into the next, by swapping every other pair of `f`s and `0`s. The "every other pair" condition is enforced by matching a zero in front of the `f`, which makes it impossible to match consecutive pairs since matches cannot overlap.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 26 bytes

```
V9%"0x%0128x"/^2 512h^2^2N
```

Port of my Python answer.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (Firefox 30+), <s>139</s> <s>113</s> <s>112</s> <s>92</s> <s>83</s> 80 bytes

```
_=>[for(x of"970123456")(f=y=>y--?f(y)+(x>6?x-4:y>>x&1&&'f'):'0x')(128)].join`
`
```

Finally hit the recursive sweet spot :-) Uses a handy-dandy string comprehension to save 3 bytes over `.map`:

```
_=>[..."970123456"].map(x=>(f=y=>y--?f(y)+(x>6?x-4:y>>x&1&&'f'):'0x')(128)).join`
`
```

`.replace` is also 83 bytes:

```
_=>"970123456".replace(/./g,x=>(f=y=>y--?f(y)+(x>6?x-4:y>>x&1&&'f'):'0x')(128)+`
`)
```

If a leading newline were allowed, this would also be 80 bytes:

```
_=>"970123456".replace(/./g,x=>(f=y=>y--?f(y)+(x>6?x-4:y>>x&1&&'f'):`
0x`)(128))
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 25 bytes

```
9r`╙╙u9╙╙\#"0x%0128x"%`Mi
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=OXJg4pWZ4pWZdTnilZnilZlcIyIweCUwMTI4eCIlYE1p&input=)

This solution uses the fact that `f(n) = 2**512//(2**2**n + 1)` (where `//` is floored division) to compure the values.

Explanation:

```
9r`╙╙u9╙╙\#"0x%0128x"%`Mi
9r`╙╙u9╙╙\#"0x%0128x"%`M   for n in range(1, 10):
      9╙╙\                   2**2**9//
   ╙╙u                                (2**2**n + 1)
          #"0x%0128x"%       pad with zeroes to 128 digits, prefix with "0x"
                        i  flatten and implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 60 bytes

```python
k=1
exec"print'0x%0128x'%int(256/k*('0'*k+'1'*k),2);k*=2;"*9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59ta8iVWpGarFRQlJlXom5QoWpgaGRRoa4K5GkYmZrpZ2tpqBuoa2VrqxsCSU0dI03rbC1bI2slLcv//wE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bubblegum](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), 65 bytes

```
00000000: c5cb 4501 0441 1043 d17b d4fc 254b d110  ..E..A.C.{..%K..
00000010: f7cb 9761 9e7a 8d45 e451 4ce4 564c 04d7  ...a.z.E.QL.VL..
00000020: 2e11 b02b 8f08 80df aa5e 11fe fc77 762c  ...+.....^...wv,
00000030: 428b 5b8e ae8b 30c1 13b6 ce8b b091 377a  B.[...0.......7z
00000040: 01                                       .
```

Obligatory Bubblegum answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>84</s> 72 bytes

Porting @orlp's answer:

```
import Text.Printf
mapM(\n->printf"0x%0128x\n"$div(2^2^9)$2^2^n+1)[0..8]
```

94 byte alternatives without the power of `Text.Printf`:

```
import Data.List
mapM(putStrLn.("0x"++))$transpose$("53"++).reverse<$>sequence(["0f"]<*[1..7])

r=[0..127]
mapM(putStrLn.("0x"++))$('5'<$r):('3'<$r):[["0f"!!mod(div x(2^y))2|x<-r]|y<-[0..6]]
```

Comment: @nimi whoops, must have had loaded `Control.Monad` in the REPL. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 216 bytes

```
@echo off
set s=5
call:c
set s=3
call:c
set a=0
set b=f
for /l %%i in (1,1,7)do call:l %%i
exit/b
:l
set s=%a%%b%
:c
for /l %%j in (0%1,1,6)do call set s=%%s%%%%s%%
echo 0x%s%
set a=%a%%a%
set b=%b%%b%
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>74</s> <s>72</s> 70 bytes

Includes the optional trailing newline.

```js
f=(i=1152)=>i--?f(i)+(i&127?'':`
0x`)+('53'[y=i>>7]||i&1<<y-2&&'f'):''
```

```js
f=(i=1152)=>i--?f(i)+(i&127?'':`
0x`)+('53'[y=i>>7]||i&1<<y-2&&'f'):''

console.log(f())
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>66 60</s> 45 bytes

```ruby
x=2;9.times{puts"0x%0128x"%(2**512/-~x);x*=x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8LWyNpSryQzN7W4uqC0pFjJoELVwNDIokJJVcNIS8vU0Ehft65C07pCy7ai9v9/AA)

Idea stolen from [orlp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101710/18535)

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell v2+, 68 bytes

```
5,3|%{"0x"+"$_"*128}
($a=1)..7|%{"0x"+('0'*$a+'f'*$a)*(128/($a*=2))}
```

PowerShell doesn't have arbitrary precision integers without using `[bigint]` calls, and those can't be easily converted to hexadecimal, so we're instead treating this as a string-based challenge.

The first line handles the repeating `5` and `3` by just doing a string multiplication out to `128` characters and tacking a `0x` on the front.

The next line loops from `$a=1` to `7`, each iteration outputting another string. Again we have the `0x` tacked onto the front, and we're doing string multiplication in the middle to construct the appropriate number of `0` and `f` concatenated together, and then doing string multiplication of *that* out to the appropriate number of characters. Note we're using variable `$a` here, and not the loop counter `$_`, so we can properly scale (otherwise we'd need to loop like `1,2,4,8,16,32,64|%{...}`, which is longer).

The resulting strings are left on the pipeline, and output via implicit `Write-Output` happens at program completion, with a newline between elements.

Answer (score 3):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 43 bytes

```
64i0fòYpÓ¨¨0«©¨f«©©û2}/²²³³òdd{3ÄÒ5jÒ3Îi0x
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=NjRpMGYbw7JZcMOTwqjCqDDCq8KpwqhmwqvCqcKpw7syfS_CssKywrPCs8OyZGR7M8OEw5I1asOSM8OOaTB4&input=)

This uses one of the longest compressed regexes I've ever needed in a V answer. Here is the more readable version, where I added a byte for readable regexes, and changed the unprintable escape character to `<esc>`

```
64i0f<esc>òYpÓö((0+)(f+)){2}/²²³³òdd{3ÄÒ5jÒ3Îi0x
```

Explanation (using the readable version):

```
64i0f<esc>                                          " Insert 64 "0f"s and escape to normal mode
          ò                      ò                  " Recursively:
           Yp                                       "   Duplicate this line
             Ó                                      "   Substitute:
              ö                                     "     (Optionally Turn the readable version on)
               ((0+)(f+))                           "     One or more '0's followed by one or more 'f's
                         {2}                        "     Repeated twice
                            /                       "   With:
                             ²²                     "     The second capture group twice (the '0's)
                               ³³                   "     Followed by the third capture group twice (the 'f's)
                                                    "   Once the search is not found, the loop will break
                                  dd                " Delete a line (because we have one too many)
                                    {               " Move to the first line
                                     3Ä             " Make three copies of this line
                                       Ò5           " Replace the first one with '5's
                                         jÒ3        " Move down a line and replace the second with '3's
                                            Î       " On every line:
                                             i0x    "   Insert a '0x'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>31</s> 30 bytes

To get pattern except for the `3`'s and `5`'s it cumulative reduces, each time doubling the chunks.

```
jm+"0x".[dd128+`3+`5.u.iNN6"0f
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%2B%220x%22.%5Bdd128%2B%603%2B%605.u.iNN6%220f&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## Vim 72 bytes

```
i0x128a5Ypll128r3o0x64a0fa0Ypqqffdt0fft0p@qq@qqwYp@qq@w@w@w@w:%s/0$
```

[TryItOnline!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=aTB4GzEyOGE1G1lwbGwxMjhyM28weBs2NGEwZhthMBtZcHFxZmZkdDBmZnQwcEBxcUBxcXdZcEBxcUB3QHdAd0B3OiVzLzAk&input=)

Unprintables:

```
i0x^[128a5^[Ypll128r3o0x^[64a0f^[a0^[Ypqqffdt0fft0p@qq@qqwYp@qq@w@w@w@w:%s/0$
```

The 4 `@w`s at the end are bugging me, but because I was relying on the `@q` to fail out at the end of a line, it fails out the @w as well.  I might try just running q 32 times and seeing if it messes up the later lines.

Answer (score 2):

## [GNU sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 77

```
s/^/0x5/
:
s/x5{,127}$/&5/
t
p
y/5/3/
p
s/33/0f/gp
:a
s/(f+)(0+f+)/\2\1/gp
ta
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##FYjRCkAwGEbv/@eQCH2btdSeRUoxuWH5d0Hy6n5zczrn8DyJMAao04IcMU5717rtngx5OpECXbAwSMIwBspjCeTGVIWvykJViejbXv8/jiLvHuK6byzNdnw)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 146 bytes

```c
#define F for(i=0;++i<129;)s[i+1]=
#define P ;puts(s);
i,j;f(){char s[131]={'0','x'};F'5'P F'3'P for(j=1;(j*=2)<129;){F(i-1)%j<j/2?'0':'f'P}}
```

Ungolfed:

```c
#define F for(i=0;++i<129;)s[i+1]=
#define P ;puts(s);
i,j;f(){
  char s[131]={'0','x'};
  F'5'P
  F'3'P
  for(j=1;(j*=2)<129;){
    F(i-1)%j<j/2?'0':'f'P 
  }
}
```

Comment: [133 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY3LCsIwFET3/YoQkdxYik2roKbBXdbdFxclNnoDVmkUhNJvj/G1GYbhcMZkJ2NCmB07i31HNLHXAVDlMk2xEsVWct9gKg4q@SO1vD3uHjyXCUoLjo/m3A7EN6KMGM2fVGq2ZjXRrIz59jklJLiFKvhXOWrATPC5q9yy2K82O2ZZPU3h0mIPfEwIsRD1nx9KY/sNU3gB "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat [Easy save](https://tio.run/##NY3LCsIwFET3/YoQkSSWYtMqqLfBXdbdFxclNnoDVmkUhNJvj/G1GYbhcMZkJ2NCmB07i31HNNjrwFHlkKZYyWILwjeYyoNK/kgNt8fdcy8gQbDcidGc24H4RpYRo/mTarZmNdGsjPnWOSWBu4UqxNc4ao6ZFHNXuWWxX212zLJ6msKlxZ6LMSHE8mj/3FAa22@Ywgs)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 211 bytes

```
+++++++>++>>-[>>>>+<<++<+<-----]>--->>++++++++++>++<<<<<<[->----[>+++<--]>-->.<.++++++++[->>>>.<<<<]>>>.>--[<]<<]+<[->>----[>+++<--]>-->.<.++++++++[<<[>+>->.<<<-]>[<+>>->>.<<<-]>]>>>.<<<<[-<+>]<[->++<]>[-<+>]<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU5bCoAwDDtQ6U4QepHSDxUEEfwQPH9NN@anYYymedD1Xo5rf7YzUwaMz9SNEEAEAi2E8ePuA0d0uJbECJcYRmto00eZaOWMGig7gkQq@R9luYlpT1N11G02acxeVwpRdayhbVBE5gs)

Comment: [197 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY5BCkJBDEMPFDsnCLlI6cL/QRDBheD5x3QGXZnFkL62mR6v6/15e5@POQEpUhZIgGC0Sn7MfrLlUka3vGLIPajBcekI@4zgUNGoKxZZQP7d@WanUwU142on11naoFTa1p8TDvcNDvLcLmvODw) through some different loop checks. I'm pretty sure the `x` generator can be moved outside the loop now

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 168 bytes

```
()={string R="",o="0",f="f";for(int i=0,j;i<9;i++){R+="0x";if(i>2){o+=o;f+=f;}for(j=0;j<128;){R+=i<1?"5":i<2?"3":o+f;j+=i>1?(int)Math.Pow(2,i-1):1;}R+="\n";}return R;};
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
⌡hÅék╝94"ºé♪╛#V┐5í╒
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=f5688f826bbc393422a7820dbe2356bf35a1d5&i=&a=1)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
512r        [0..511]
{:Brm       convert each to bits and reverse each
M           transpose matrix, filling missing elements in rectangle with zero
m           map over each element of array, using the rest of the program.  outputs implicitly.
  4/        split bits into groups of 4
  {:b|Hm    convert each 4-bit binary number to single digit hex string
  .0xp      print "0x" without newline
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=512r++++%09[0..511]%0A%7B%3ABrm+++%09convert+each+to+bits+and+reverse+each%0AM+++++++%09transpose+matrix,+filling+missing+elements+in+rectangle+with+zero%0Am+++++++%09map+over+each+element+of+array,+using+the+rest+of+the+program.++outputs+implicitly.%0A++4%2F++++%09split+bits+into+groups+of+4%0A++%7B%3Ab%7CHm%09convert+each+4-bit+binary+number+to+single+digit+hex+string%0A++.0xp++%09print+%220x%22+without+newline&i=)

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 193 bytes

```
/*/\/\///X/
0x*F/5555*G/FFFF*T/3333*U/TTTT*o/0f0f*1/oooo*t/00ff*2/tttt*g/0000*h/ffff*4/ghgh*6/gghh*7/gggg*8/hhhh*9/7788/0xGGGGGGGGXUUUUUUUUX11111111X22222222X44444444X66666666X78787878X99X77988
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LccxDoMwEETRPkeZZhZCsH0BuECQtkiTIt4tIlFAwe2dleL3i9Ec3/fhn6M1gq@IVN7kwsJHwMol4Ml7wMZnwE6pUjFwDzgpUitGngEWTwTOGjDR3BwzzdyRYsyQ6QGFKeVMudZOt06HTsdOp07nTlP@p6VoSiXn1n4)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 72 bytes

```javascript
n=1n<<512n;f=(i=2n)=>i-n?`
0x`+(n/-~i+n).toString(16).slice(1)+f(i*i):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDsIgEAXQvRfpjASUJrrQoofwAm0QmjHkjynEuPLq@N5r@Sw1bvJuFvpMvSN4TNPJj7jmQBJGcLiJxX3eHb@zIRzsTwzYNX20TbCSP7OrRWIizyaT7IUvw9CjompJruhKmZj7Hw)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 69 bytes from Arnauld's

```javascript
f=(i=4608)=>i?f(i-=4)+(i&508?'':`
0x`)+('53'[y=i>>9]||i&1<<y&&'f'):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchRCoMwDADQ/x2kSRClYzpUTD2IDBS1I1KsqMgE7975Pt/UHd3Wr7Ls8eyHMQTLKJy@dU5spLYoMacUoahM5zVA2T70r70Dshc0J4sxxee6RD2r6lQKLFAJEHo/b96NifNftEgU/g)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 136 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 17 bytes

```
‛0x53f‛0f6ʀE•J₇vẎ+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJqPSIsIiIsIuKAmzB4NTNm4oCbMGY2yoBF4oCiSuKCh3bhuo4rIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Math? No we don't do that here. We do string manipulation instead.

### Explained

```
‛0x53f‛0f6ʀE•J₇vẎ+­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
      ‛0f           # ‎⁡The string "0f"...
            •       # ‎⁢with each character repeated n times...
         6ʀE        # ‎⁣for each n in [2**x for x in range(0, 7)].
             J      # ‎⁤Appended to...
   53f              # ‎⁢⁡the list [5, 3].
# ‎⁢⁢The top of the stack is [5, 3, "0f", "00ff", "0000ffff", ...]
              ₇vẎ   # ‎⁢⁣Take the first 128 items of each item.
                    # ‎⁢⁣This reuses previous digit/chars if the item isn't long enough
‛0x              +  # ‎⁢⁤Add the string "0x" to each item
# ‎⁣⁡The j flag joins on newlines before printing

 Created with the help of Luminespire at https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire
```